# How to open a selected nested list on Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a code in React where I have two list menus that have nested menus.

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List
          component="nav"
        >
          <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary="Files" />
            {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="Providers" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="Insurance Companies" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary="Utilities" />
            {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="Excel Templates" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="Upload File" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the first menu, the second menu also opens. How do I only open one menu and the other one remains closed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to have two seperate values in state in order to only open one at a time

```
state = { openMenu1: false, openMenu2: false }
```

And the click events should trigger only one of those to go to true/false.
Make sure to change the variable in the Collapse component to use the corresponding state as well